# Nginx redirect to another domain without trailing uri

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I am trying to get `http://foo.mydomain.xyz/one/two/three.json` by calling `http://bar.mydomain.xyz/cat/one/two/three.json`. I am using the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name bar.mydomain.xyz;
        absolute_redirect off;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        location /cat {
          rewrite ^(/cat) http://foo.mydomain.xyz$request_uri permanent;
        }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name foo.mydomain.xyz;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:7070;
        }
}
```

Using this configuration when I am calling: `http://bar.mydomain.xyz/cat/` it is redirecting me to `http://foo.mydomain.xyz/` successfully. But when I am calling `http://bar.mydomain.xyz/cat/one/two/three.json` it is returning `http://foo.mydomain.xyz/cat/one/two/three.json`. Notice the **/cat** is not removing from the url. How can I solve this?

Comment: `$request_uri` is the original URI, you need to capture the latter part of the URI in the `rewrite` regex. Try: `rewrite ^/cat/(.*)$ http://foo.mydomain.xyz/$1 permanent;`

Comment: @RichardSmith You can post this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rewrite` statement is changing the domain name but nothing else. The value of `$request_uri` is the original URI including the leading `/cat` part. You need to capture the latter part of the URI in the regular expression.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/cat/(.*)$ http://foo.example.com/$1 permanent;
```

Or maybe:

```
rewrite ^/cat(?:/(.*))?$ http://foo.example.com/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: in my case I am trying to go to `https://foo.mydomain.xyz/bar/v1/search?text=mytext&size=25` from `https://bar.mydomain.xyz/v1/search?text=mytext&size=25`. When I trying `rewrite` it is redirecting only to `https://bar.mydomain.xyz/v1/search` portion. Parameters are not passing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to capture the part in the `location` directive:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location ~ ^/cat(/.+)$ {
    return 301 http://foo.example.com$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: It is returning `invalid number of arguments in "return" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com:19`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I left an extra `permanent` word over there.

Comment: @tero-kilman, in my case I am trying to go to `https://foo.mydomain.xyz/bar/v1/search?text=mytext&size=25` from `https://bar.mydomain.xyz/v1/search?text=mytext&size=25`. When I trying `return` it is redirecting only to `https://bar.mydomain.xyz/v1/search` portion. Parameters are not passing.

Comment: I added the arguments to the redirect in my answer.